# problema ao fazer uma biblioteca

Tags: c

Fiz um código em uma biblioteca e quando chamo ela na main ele da um erro **collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status**
segue os códigos
biblioteca.c

```
#include "biblioteca.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char *getPath(char *fullPath){
    int i,tam;
    char *recebe;

    tam = strlen(fullPath);
    recebe =(char*) malloc (tam * sizeof (char));

    for(i=tam;i>=0;i--){
        if(*(fullPath+i)=='/')
            break;
    }
    strncpy(recebe,fullPath,i);
    *(recebe+i)='\0';

    return recebe;
}

char *getFileName(char *fullPath){
    char *recebe;
    int i,tam;

    tam=strlen(fullPath);

    for(i=tam;i>=0;i--){
        if(*(fullPath+i)=='/')
            break;
        tam--;
    }
    i=strlen(fullPath)-i-1;
    recebe=(char*)malloc (i * sizeof (char));
    strncpy(recebe,&fullPath[tam+1],i);
    *(recebe+i)='\0';

    return recebe;
}

char *getSuffix(char *name){
    char *sufixo;
    int i,tam,onde;

    tam=strlen(name);
    onde=tam;

    for(i=tam;i>=0;i--){
        if(*(name+i)=='.'){
            break;
        }
        onde--;
    }
    i=tam+1-i;
    sufixo =(char*) malloc (i * sizeof (char));

    strncpy(sufixo,&name[tam+1],i);
    *(sufixo+i)='\0';

    return sufixo;
}

int hasSlash(char *path){
    int verdade=0,tam;
    tam=strlen(path)-1;
    if(*(path+tam)=='/')
        verdade=1;
    return verdade;

}

char *concatPathFile(char *path, char *fileName){
    int tamPath,tamFile;
    char *concatena;

    tamPath = strlen(path);
    tamFile = strlen(fileName);

    concatena =(char*) malloc ((tamPath+tamFile-1) * sizeof (char));
    if (hasSlash(path) == 1){

        strcpy(concatena,path);
        strcat(concatena,fileName);
    }
    else{

        strcpy(concatena,path);
        strcat(concatena,"/");
        strcat(concatena,fileName);
    }

    return concatena;
}
```

biblioteca.h

```
#ifndef BIBLIOTECA_H_INCLUDED
#define BIBLIOTECA_H_INCLUDED

char *getPath(char *fullPath);
/*
Dado o nome completamente qualificado de um arquivo,
retorna o caminho, sem ‘/’ no final. 
*/

char *getFileName(char *fullPath);
/*
Retorna o nome do arquivo, incluindo a extensão
*/

char *getSuffix(char *name);
/*
Retorna a extensão do arquivo. 
O nome do arquivo pode ser precedido ou não por um caminho absoluto ou relativo.
*/

int hasSlash(char *path);
/*
Retorna verdadeiro se o caminho “path” termina em ‘/’; falso, caso contrário.
*/

char *concatPathFile(char *path, char *fileName);
/*
Qualifica o arquivo de nome fileName com o caminho path. Ou seja, concatena o segundo (fileName) após o primeiro (path). 
Caso path não termine com /, acrescenta esta barra entre o path e o fileName.
*/

#endif
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "biblioteca.h"

void print(char *texto){
    printf("%s",texto);
}

int main(){
    char *caminho1="a/b/c";
    

    print(getFileName(caminho1));
    return 0;
}
```

no caso o main foi mais para testar

Comment: Perguntar antes, você gerou o .o, por exemplo da lib antes da compilação? segunda é o gcc? terceiro este print() seu, faz parte da sua lib ou já seria um erro na sintaxe?

Comment: sim gerei, n sei se é o gcc (usei o code blocks), o print é uma funcao na main (queria ver se ia funcionar)

Comment: No caso do gcc, quais os comandos que eu deveria usar?

Comment: Para o codeblock, no Windows, acho que usa o MinGW, então acredito que os comandos vão funcionar. Tenta ai: ... pera ai que vou postar embaixo aqui nao deu muito certo

Comment: Testando seu código aqui, seguido as instruções abaixo, no Linux com GCC compilou corretamente. Então erro no codigo na compilação não tem mesmo, é mais que questão de linkagem. Ai se não der certo estas flags, teria que ver o que co codeblock precisar para gerar uma linkagem estática.. as vezes pode mudar um termo ou outro, mas o problemas esta ai neste link statico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se der para passar via terminar vai você passa

```
gcc(se for gcc ai ou outro comando) -c biblioteca.o biblioteca.c
```

Vai gerar um binário e com ele você vai compilar com o main para linkar corretamente.

```
gcc -o nome_da_saida main.c biblioteca.o
```

Isso vai gerar um executável único. Tem outras formas de compilar, mas esta funciona.

Se estiver usando o LLVM acredito que serão as mesmas flags, para Compilador da Microsoft eu nem imagino, já que não uso Windows.

Se por alguma motivo não der se certifique dos comandos passados nas opções do codeblock, mas o ideal mesmo é que faça os comandos na mãos ou gere um arquivo do tipo make ou ninja ou quem usando algo como o cmake(nao gosto, mas ta ai, ele existe), meson. Para poucas alinhas as vezes não compensa, mas para muitas linhas de comando vai precisar.

Para a função print, como ela não modifica muito seria melhor usar uma macro de função ou passar printf direto, vai ficar melhor para você debbugar se for o próprio printf.

```
#define print(x) \
    printf("%s\n", x)
```

Veja ai se rola, se não rolar, manda mensagens que tentamos outra solução.

Comment: Isso aparece qnd uso "-c biblioteca.o biblioteca.c" ele retorna essa mensagem
"gcc.exe: warning: biblioteca.o: linker input file unused because linking not done"
Já no "gcc -o nome_da_saida main.c biblioteca.o" o que seria "nome_da_saida"?

Comment: Nome da saida é o nome do arquivo final. Por exemplos e voce não der nome nenhum usando -o ==  output no linux vai sair com o nome do antigo formato a.out como nome padrão do executação. no Windows pode ser que saia algo.exe, mas você pode definir o nome da saida final do executavel.

Comment: E sobre o linker, esta falando que a saida não foi utilizada. Pode ser que ele tele tenha alguma regra no compilador que busque o nome com ofmrato do arquivo objeto que será linkado depois. Na hora de executar o ultimo comando do gcc você precisa ter os nomes corretos para o compilador encontrar o arquivo. Tente fazer a compição completa via terminal usando este gcc.exe no diretorio que você está gerando a compilação. Depois se der certo tenta configurar o codeblock, pelo menos assim você já pega como funciona um pouco mais da etapa de compilação do gcc.